# Can history.pushState do anything other than an xhr request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history

I'm currently building a project and I'm having a bit of trouble.

You see, I'm trying to get a registration page to load and with it being an XHR request. It's returning the output of the PHP code because it's an XHR request.

I want it to load as a document instead of it being an XHR request but I don't know if history.pushState can do that.

So... Can history.pushState make it a GET document request instead of a GET XHR request?

This is my project.

https://159.203.212.19/

Comment: you can post your url with picture , it more safes for us

Answer (score 0):

The pushstate API is completely independent of Ajax, XHR or any other technology.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

There used to be a game called `URL Hunter` which turned the location bar into a game.  (Alas, the game is dead, but the old URL was http://probablyinteractive.com/url-hunter).